# How do I solve a cubic equation for values of x?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I have partially differentiated an equation w.r.t. x, see picture below, and want to isolate x in the equation to solve for a local maximum.

Can I use Mathematica to get it on a cubic form? and how do I solve the cubic equation for values of x?

Attached there is a picture of the equation as it looks in the paper and below is my Mathematica code.

Code:

```
Solve[
    \[Alpha]*(ph - pl)*(R1 + R2*\[Gamma]*\[Lambda]*( { {x*(ph)^2 + (1 - x)*(pl)^2}, {x*ph + (1 - x)*pl} } - { {x*(1 - ph)*ph + (1 - x)*(1 - pl)*pl}, {x*(1 - ph) + (1 - x)*(1 - pl)} }) + R2*( { {(1 - \[Gamma]*\[Lambda])}, {1 + r} } )) - 2*b*[Phi]*x == 0, x]
]
```

Ideally, I would like to get it on cubic form, find values/roots of x that solves the equation and simplify it.

I hope you can help.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try `Solve` instead of `solve`.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Of course, sorry for the inconvenience. Here is my code: 
solve[\[Alpha]*(ph - pl)*(R1 + R2*\[Gamma]*\[Lambda]*( {
          {x*(ph)^2 + (1 - x)*(pl)^2},
          {x*ph + (1 - x)*pl}
         } - {
          {x*(1 - ph)*ph + (1 - x)*(1 - pl)*pl},
          {x*(1 - ph) + (1 - x)*(1 - pl)}
         }) + R2*( {
         {(1 - \[Gamma]*\[Lambda])},
         {1 + r}
        } )) - 2*b*\[Phi]*x == 0, x]

Comment: Your code should be: `Solve[(ph - pl) \[Alpha] (R1 + R2 (-(((1 - pl) pl (1 - x) + (1 - ph) ph x)/((1 - pl) (1 -  x) + (1 - ph) x)) + (pl^2 (1 - x) + ph^2 x)/(pl (1 - x) + ph x)) \[Gamma] \[Lambda] + (R2 (1 - \[Gamma] \[Lambda]))/(1 + r)) - 2 b \[Phi] x == 0, x]`. Braces are used for lists, to group terms use parentheses. Commands start with capital letters, hence write `Solve`.